# What is the location of "NT Authority\Network Service" home directory?

Tags: java, windows, network-service

I have an java application for which its cache gets created in under `C:\Users\<User>`. But when application runs as `NT Authority\Network Service` where does its cache get created ?

Comment: It depends on the program, but probably `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService`

Comment: Hey @HarryJohnston, Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can be found here %systemroot%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService

Usually %systemroot% translates to "C:\Windows". "systemroot" is an environment variable in windows that holds the path "C:\Windows" depending on your Windows OS installation location.

**Edit:** It completely depends on an application to create its cache. But most of the developers use user's home directory to maintain applications cache.